# How to find the shortest string in a list in Python

Tags: python

This seems like a pretty simple problem, but I'm looking for a short and sweet way of doing it that is still understandable (this isn't code golf).

Given a list of strings, what's the easiest way to find the shortest string?

The way that is most obvious to me is roughly:

```
l = [...some strings...]
lens = map(l, len)
minlen, minind = min(lens)
shortest = l[minind]
```

but that seems like a lot of code for this problem (at least in python).

Answer (score 184, accepted):

[The `min` function](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#min) has an optional parameter `key` that lets you specify a function to determine the "sorting value" of each item. We just need to set this to [the `len` function](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#len) to get the shortest value:

```
strings = ["some", "example", "words", "that", "i", "am", "fond", "of"]

print min(strings, key=len) # prints "i"
```

Answer (score 3):

Takes linear time:

```
   reduce(lambda x, y: x if len(x) < len(y) else y, l)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use `sorted(l, key=len)[0]`

Comment: That's overkill. Besides being conceptually too complex of an answer, sorting is `O(n log n)` while `min` is `O(n)`.

Comment: @delnan I don't know if I agree with "conceptually complex", but I agree using `min` is much better (and also the reduce variant posted later).

Comment: Not to mention inefficient for large input, it was also wrong, returning the _longest_ string instead. Fixed that at least...

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to use an explicit loop. This implementation returns `None` when the iterable is empty.

```
def smallest_string(iterable):
    res = None
    for x in iterable:
        if res is None or len(x) < len(res):
            res = x
    return res

strings = ["some", "example", "words", "that", "i", "am", "fond", "of"]
print(smallest_string(strings))
```

The behavior with empty iterables is the main differentiation factor of the current solutions.

- The `min(iterable, key=len)` solution raises a `ValueError: min() arg is an empty sequence`.
- The `functools.reduce(lambda x, y: x if len(x) < len(y) else y, iterable)` solution raises a `TypeError: reduce() of empty iterable with no initial value`. Giving it an initial value does not work as the lambda will get called with that.
- `sorted(iterable, key=len)[0]` raises `IndexError: list index out of range`.
- This implementation returns `None`. It could be modified to return the empty string or to raise an error (possibly with the `for` + `else` construct).

Answer (score -1):

Potential answer:

```
l = [...some strings...]
l.sort(key=len)
shortest = l[0]
```

However, this is probably very inefficient in that it sorts the entire list, which is unnecessary. We really just need the minimum.

Comment: This also has the side effect that the input list no longer has the same order. `min()` will take the leftmost shortest string which is another behaviour as `list.sort()`. See this: `min(["arthur", "Arthur"], key=len)` will return `"arthur"` and provided code will return `"Arthur"` instead.

Answer (score -1):

As suggested in other answers, these solutions takes linear time. They need need to be guarded against empty iterables though:

```
import functools

strings = ["small str", "xs", "long string"]

if (strings):
    print( "shortest string:", functools.reduce(lambda x, y: x if len(x) < len(y) else y, strings) )
    # or if you use min:
    # print( "shortest string:", min(strings, key=len) )
else:
    print( "list of strings is empty" )
```

Answer (score -1):

To find the shortest string in a list:

```
str = ['boy', 'girl', 'lamb', 'butterfly']

def len_str(string):
  return len(string)

def compare_len(list):
  x = []
  for i in range(len(list)):
    x.append(len_str(list[i]))
  return min(x) #change to max if you're looking for the largest length

compare_len(str)
```

Comment: Why do you define a function `len_str` which is just a wrapper of `len`? Also you should iterate on elements instead of indices: `for x in y: res.append(len(x))`. Lastly note that you override both `str` and `list` which are built-in names

Answer (score -2):

```
arr=('bibhu','prasanna','behera','jhgffgfgfgfg')
str1=''

#print (len(str))
for ele in arr:
    print (ele,ele[::-1])
    if len(ele)>len(str1):
        str1=ele
    elif len(ele)<len(str2):
        str2=ele
print ("the longest element is :",str1)
str2=arr[0]
for ele in arr:
    if len(ele)<len(str2):
        str2=ele

print ("the shortest element is :",str2)
```