# Find *all* shortest strings in a list

Tags: python

I want to print the shortest strings in a list.
for example the output for:

```
names=["Hans", "Anna", "Vladimir", "Michael", "Ed", "Susan", "Janice", "Jo"]
```

will be

```
"Ed", "Jo"
```

The output for

```
names=["Hans", "Anna", "Vladimir", "Michael", "Ed", "Susan", "Janice", "Jo", "Al"]
```

will be:

```
"Ed", "Jo", "Al"


[x for x in names if x==min(names, key=len)]
```

will get only one of them, but will not help in cases where there is more than one.

Comment: Are you able to write a function that returns one of them?

Comment: [x for x in names if x==min(names, key=len)]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7228924/how-to-find-the-shortest-string-in-a-list-in-python?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Just like find the minimal or max value of an array, but you have to use a list to store all the "min"s instead of a variable.

Comment: no, these will give the shortest string. I want all the shortest strings. min just picks the first str in a tie. I want all the shortest strings that were tied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass `len` as `key` to the `min` method and get the length of the smallest string and then use list comprehension as:

```
names=["Hans", "Anna", "Vladimir", "Michael", "Ed", "Susan", "Janice", "Jo"]
smallest_len = len(min(names, key=len))
smallest = [name for name in names if len(name) == smallest_len]
```

Answer (score 1):

First find the ***length*** of the shortest string:

```
shortest = min(map(len, names))
```

Now just find all strings with that length:

```
print([name for name in names if len(name) == shortest])
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to make this a one-liner?

Comment: @DanEran Yes but then you will repeatedly call `min`. Why it bothers you saving the `min` with one extra line? Short code is not (always) better code...

Answer (score 0):

```py
names = ["Hans", "Anna", "Vladimir", "Michael", "Ed", "Susan", "Janice", "Jo"]
smallest_len = len(min(names, key=len))
shorts = []
for name in names:
    if len(name) == smallest_len:
        shorts.append(name)
print(shorts)
```

Comment: @Tomerikoo oh thanks, it took me over a minute to figure out why I am "comparing a string to an int" !

Answer (score 0):

Based on the question, my guess is that you're a Python beginner, so I really don't want to introduce you to advanced pythonic concepts.

Using no advanced concepts of the language, it's straight forward:

```
names = ["Hans", "Anna", "Vladimir", "Michael", "Ed", "Susan", "Janice", "Jo"]


def get_all_shortest_strings(strings: list) -> list:  # Accept a list of strings and return a list of strings as well
    shortest_strings = []               # Start with an empty list. This is the identity element for list addition
    shortest_length = 9999999999999999  # Start with a huge number. This is the identity element for the minimum() function
    for string in strings:              # Go through all strings.
        if len(string) == shortest_length:    # Found one of the same length? 
            shortest_strings.append(string)   # Add it!
        if len(string) < shortest_length:     # Found a shorter one?
            shortest_strings = []             # Clear all longer ones
            shortest_strings.append(string)   # Add the one we just found
            shortest_length = len(string)     # remember the length
    return shortest_strings


assert ["Ed", "Jo"] == get_all_shortest_strings(names)
```

You may want to read about the [identity element](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_element#Examples). Basically it says that this element will not change the result of a given operation.

You may also not have seen [`assert`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5142418/what-is-the-use-of-assert-in-python) before. You can use asserts for checking if your code works, without the need of printing something.

Answer (score -1):

To loop only once, and call `len` on each item once:

```py
names = [
    "Hans", "Anna", "Vladimir", "Michael", "Ed", "Susan", "Janice", "Jo", "Al"
]


def find_shortests(names: list):
    result = []
    shortest = float("inf")
    for x in names:
        n = len(x)
        if n > shortest:
            continue
        if n < shortest:
            result.clear()
        shortest = n
        result.append(x)
    return result


print(find_shortests(names))
# ['Ed', 'Jo', 'Al']
```

Comment: Can anyone tell me what is wrong with my code before downvoting?